# mysqli result in array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this table produced from the query `SELECT * FROM myTable`

```
+--------------------------+---------+--------+
| Name                     | Version | Detail |
+--------------------------+---------+--------+
| name0                    |      10 | xxx    |
| name1                    |      30 | yyy    |
| name2                    |      30 | zzz    |
| name3                    |      30 | kkk    |
+--------------------------+---------+--------+
```

so, i need to have this table in a php array using mysqli function.

```
//$this->internalDB have the db connection
$result = $this->internalDB->query($query)->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($result);
```

produced

```
Array ( [Name] => name0 [Version] => 10 [Detail] => xxx )
```

cycles with the speech does not change ...

how i can do that?

Comment: How about [this](http://il1.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) ?

Comment: You mean, echo the results using a `foreach` or `while` loop?

Comment: I tried, but the result I get and only the first line ...

Comment: You need to show us what you tried, code-wise. There are few ways to do this. No sense commenting till the cows come home. Putting in an answer and to potentially comment in that also, in order to get the proper results, isn't my cup of tea, as it were.

Comment: What part of this project are you stuck on?  Running the query in PHP?  Getting the results?  Printing them as a table?

Comment: After seeing your code sample.  *Please* do **not** chain SQL functions like that!  `fetch_array()` returns one row when called.  When called again, it returns the next row.  Normally it's called like: `while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))` to loop over all the rows.  You *need* to break up that chain and follow the example in the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will query a database and return your values as an associative array in the $arrReturn variable.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$sqlRes = $mysqli->query($query);

if (is_object($sqlRes)) {
    $arrReturn = array();

    while ($row = $sqlRes->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arrRow = array();
        foreach($row as $field => $value) {
            $arrRow[$field] = $value;
        }
        $arrReturn[] = $arrRow;
    }

    echo $arrReturn[0]['Name']; // prints 'name0'
}
```

It might be helpful to read through the [mysqli quickstart guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.php)